# Windows Service "Service could not be started" from EventLog call

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-services, event-log

I'm trying to write an event log when the windows service is started.  I'm using the property of the service, EventLog, which writes to the application log by default, like:

```
EventLog.WriteEntry("Service is starting up", EventLogEntryType.Information)
```

When I start the service using the net start command, it gives me

> Service could not be started

error.  When I remove these lines, it works just fine.  Using the default:

```
System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("Application","Service is starting up", EventLogEntryType.Information)
```

works just fine.  Why is the default not working?

Answer (score 1):

There is no static `WriteEntry` method on the [`EventLog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.writeentry%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class as defined in your call (one that takes a `string` and a `EventLogEntryType`).

There is an instance method with that signature and its [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fc682h09%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states:

> You must set the Source property on your EventLog component before you
>   can write entries to the log. You must create and configure the event
>   source before writing the first entry with the source.

So, I assume you are using the instance method and you are failing to set the source.

Comment: I just want to use "Application" log.  If I wanted to use application, where do I set that?  I can't remember where, if I did, set it for the other services where this works without issue?

Comment: Where are you creating your EventLog instance?  Set the application log there.  Or you could always just write wrapper functions around the WriteEntry methods to hard code the application event log

Comment: The method that you posted that is not working is an instance method. Is it possible you have your own `EventLog` class that wraps the `System.Diagnostics.EventLog`?

Comment: No wrapping around eventlog

Comment: The code you posted as not working does not compile with the out of the box eventlog.  Something else is going on there.

Comment: Again, servicebase has eventlog as a property, and it defaults the source for you.  This is the first time I had an issue with that...

Comment: Now I get it.  I wasn't putting it together that ServiceBase provides an instance to you.  What exception are you getting when the service fails to start? You can use Debugger.Launch to attach a debugger before the first line of code to attach the debugger and look into the state of the EventLog object.